# Can molecular systems display negative magnetic susceptibility of a higher magnitude than bismuth?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, electronic-configuration, organometallic-compounds, magnetism

Bismuth has the biggest value when it comes to a negative magnetic susceptibility than all other elements, ignoring superconductors, as they would have a value of -1.
Yet, when tables displaying diamagnetic materials show these, none show those shown by molecular systems above Bismuth. Are there any molecules or compounds with a higher negative negative susceptibility than Bismuth?
Any examples?

Comment: Pyrolytic carbon supposedly has higher diamagnetism than bismuth metal. It is easy to demonstrate the diamagnetism of a graphite pencil lead (a refill lead for a mechanical pencil) by using two of the pencil leads and a strong Nd-B-Fe magnet. I used to do this demo in class. Lay one pencil lead on the table top, lay the other one across it, like a tiny see-saw, then move the magnet close to the top pencil lead: it will move away from the magnet. For the demo, I did this using a video overhead projector in the lecture hall, so everyone could see it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Are there any examples for singular molecular systems with diamagnetism stronger than bismuth?

Comment: I have no idea. If I had to guess, I would say no simply because “combining” something diamagnetic with something less diamagnetic does not look like a winner. But it would be nice to be proven wrong, so maybe a good answer will happen.